# Binding DHCP scope to particular network card

Tags: dhcp

I have a windows 2012 server running DHCP. This server has in two network cards. I need to assign Ip addresses across two Vlans. Can this server be configured to assign addresses via scope1 via network card A to VLAN1  and scope2 via network card B to  VLAN2?
I have already set up the new scope but not sure on how to bind the new scope to network card B.

Comment: You can't bind the scope to the network card but as Zoredache pointed out in his answer, this should work based on which interface the DHCPD traffic is received on. As long as you have a scope defined that is correct for each interface it should just work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should 'just work' by default.  DHCP servers take into account the IP address of the interface on which the incoming request was received.  In the case of relays the IP of the interface the relay received the request is included as part of the forwarded request.

So if a computer receives a request on the interface `192.168.63.1/24`, then it will assign an address from the `192.168.63.0/24` scope.

So all you should have to make sure the VLAN2 interface has a static address assigned that is valid for that network, and then activate the scope.

Comment: Many thanks, I tried this and it works like a charm. many thanks for your input

Comment: @Zoredache it does not just work. I have done the same thing and the DHCP does not Offer on the LAN i need it to offer on. Have you come across this?